# Json-editor: searching a online-tool that supports my team by building a complex json-schema/model

Tags: json, jsonschema, collaborative-editing, jsoneditor

We are a remote-working team with the upcoming challenge to build, edit, share and document a complex json-datamodel-scheme.

For this task we are searching a tool that fits our needs in this process:

- browser-based preferred (no local installation)
- host the source
- multiuser/auth
- edit-mode: tree/column-view in addition to code-view
- fast navigating to $refs
- export as schema-documentation

All tools we have tested so far lack on some of our points and we did not find an appropriate solution...

Maybe we get some advice from community here

Thanks

Comment: May I ask, why is it a requirement that it is an online tool?

Comment: Which tools did you look at so far?

Comment: primarly I am searching an out-of-the-box online-solution
but if there is no tool which meets our needs this way,
a local solution with git would also be suitable...

graphical Visualization during editing-process is important, because not all in my team are familiar with json-schema-syntax.

so far https://jsonhero.io looks nice from frontend-perspective, but does not offer a storage/hosting/collaboration - but I left a message with my questions to its owner

Comment: I am the developer of JSONBuddy (https://www.json-buddy.com). I am happy to answer any questions if you want to review the tool in detail. From my experience, if you are going to build a complex JSON Schema, the built-in debugger helps a lot.